# type="hidden" の値を JavaScript で受け取るには

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

タイムリーフでationNameListとationIdListの二つのリストの変数をJavaScriptに渡します。

受けた変数のリスト２つで、
`<input type="text" th:field="*{ationName}" onclick="check()" id="ationName">`
上記のinputタグに入力された名前と一致するIDを

`<input type="hidden" th:field="*{ationId}">`
上記のinputタグで表示させたいです。

その時JavaScriptでの条件式についての質問がしたいです。
例　山田　太郎が入力された値として、担当の教師のIDを取得したいです。
山田　太郎のationNameに対して担当の教師のationIdを取得するJavaScriptを教えていただきたいです。

```
function check(param){
    var ationName;
    var ationId;
    if(ationId != null){
        document.getElementById("ationId");
    }else{
        document.getElementById("ationId").value;
    }
}
```

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{ationName}" onclick="check()" id="ationName">
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{ationId}">
```

**HTML**

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        var objName = /*[[${ationNameList}]]*/ {};
        var objId = /*[[${ationIdList}]]*/ {};
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

本来は、`type="hidden"`になっている`input`に対しても、適切に`name`属性を定義するべきところですが、`nextElementSibling`等を使えば取得できると思います。

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling

もしくは、`th:field`が実際に何を出力するかにもよりますが、`data-text-id`等の属性を定義して、`querySelector`などで参照する方法もあります。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector